# Relative frequency by category SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a table with columns: `date, category, views`.

I'd like to write a query that gives me the following output:

`year, quarter, category, "relative percentage of category views by quarter"`

For example:

```
2013, Q1, blue, 0.15
2013, Q1, yellow, 0.05
2013, Q1, green, 0.80
2013, Q2, blue, 0.20
2013, Q2, yellow, 0.05
2013, Q2, green, 0.75
2013, Q3, blue, 0.10
2013, Q3, yellow, 0.15
2013, Q3, green, 0.65
```

**Note that for each quarter the relative frequencies add up to 1 across the set of categories.**

Is this simply too much state to handle dynamically with only SQL (I'm using MySQL)?

This is what I have so far.

It's nearly what I want, except the relative frequencies output sum to 1 across all quarters.

```
SET @total_views = SELECT sum(views) FROM daily_views_by_category;

SELECT
    year(dt),
    quarter(dt),
    category,
    sum(views)/@total_views AS category_views
FROM
    daily_views_by_category
GROUP BY
    year(dt), quarter(dt), category
ORDER BY
    year(dt), quarter(dt), category
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this with a `join` rather than a variable.  The idea is to summarize the data by year-quarter-catalog and also by year-quarter and then join the results together to do the arithmetic:

```
SELECT yqc.yr, yqc.qt, category,
       (yqc.views / yq.views) as category_views
FROM (select year(dt) as yr, quarter(dt) as qt, category, sum(views) as views
      from daily_views_by_category vbc
      group by year(dt), quarter(dt), category
     ) yqc join
     (select year(dt) as yr, quarter(dt) as qt, sum(views) as views
      from daily_views_by_category vbc
      group by year(dt), quarter(dt)
     ) yq
     on yqc.yr = yq.yr and yqc.qt = yq.qt
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Case for using the aggregate functions. Since MySQL 8.0.2, the engine supports aggregate/window functions, but I haven't tested it.

```
SELECT year(dt)
       ,quarter(dt)
       ,category
       ,SUM(views) 
       ,SUM(views)*1.0/SUM(SUM(views)) OVER (PARTITION BY year(dt), quarter(dt))
  FROM daily_views_by_category
 GROUP BY 
       year(dt)
       ,quarter(dt)
       ,category
```